# Mysql - Combine data from table

Tags: mysql

In table 'A' I have the data:

```
nameField1 nameField2 nameField3
        a1         b1         c1
        a2
        a3         b2
```

Does anyone know how I can get next combine row?

```
nameField1 nameField2 nameField3
        a3         b2         c1
```

Comment: What is the criteria to combine columns?

Comment: use `MAX()`, `SELECT MAX(nameField1), MAX(nameField2), MAX(nameField3) ....`

Answer (score 2):

sisnce you didnt say how you want combine then maybe you looking for this

```
select max(nameField1)Field1 , max(nameField2)field2,max(nameField3)field3 From A
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f8178/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the requested row via

```
SELECT 'a3' AS nameField1, 'b2' AS nameField2, 'c1' AS nameField3
```

or

```
SELECT 
MAX(nameField1) AS nameField1, 
MAX(nameField2) AS nameField2, MAX(nameField3) AS nameField3
FROM A
```

or definitly in thousands of other ways.

By telling us, what you do want to achieve, you make it possible for us, to select the best answer.

Comment: I have a table "A" (its like history table) that contains the all changes of rows from another table (lets call it parent table "B"). In table "A" every row has the time of adding. So I want to find the latest data, that refer to exact period of time. The result row should have the latest data from every column. Besides, data "group by" rowID from B table.